# Using a change handler to add/remove likes from verses

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm making a public prayer journal where you can also add verses in full stack. You can also like verses, likes are also the many to many. I have everything working, except for a change handler where when a verse is liked, it adds a like to the database(python/django) and when one unlikes a verse it deletes a like from the database. I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Like button:

```
<FormControlLabel
          control={(
            <Checkbox
              icon={<FavoriteBorder />}
              checkedIcon={<Favorite />}
              name="checkedH"
              checked={!!userLikesArray.find((ul) => id === ul.verse_id)}
            />
            )}
        />
```

Data module:

```
const getLikeByUser = (id) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fetch(`${clientCredentials.databaseURL}/userlikes?user=${id}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(resolve)
    .catch(reject);
});

const deleteUserLike = (userLikeId) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fetch(`${clientCredentials.databaseURL}/userlikes/${userLikeId}`, {
    method: 'DELETE',
  })
    .then(resolve)
    .catch(reject);
});

const createUserLike = (userLike) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const userLikeObj = {
    verse_id: Number(userLike.verseId),
    uid: String(userLike.uid),
  };
  fetch(`${clientCredentials.databaseURL}/userlikes`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(userLikeObj),
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
    .then((response) => resolve(response.json()))
    .catch((error) => reject(error));
});
```

index.js:

```
    function Home() {
      const { user } = useAuth();
      const [userLikesArray, setUserLikesArray] = useState([]);
      const [Verses, setVerses] = useState([]);
      const router = useRouter();
      useEffect(() => {
        getVerses().then((setVerses));
      }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getLikeByUser(user.id).then(setUserLikesArray);
  }, [user]);

      return (
        <article className="verses">
          <h1>Verses</h1>
          <Link href="/verses/new" passHref>
            <Button variant="info">Add a Verse</Button>
          </Link>
          {Verses.map((Verse) => (
            <VerseCard
              key={Verse.id}
              id={Verse.id}
              verse={Verse.verse}
              content={Verse.content}
              firstName={user.first_name}
              lastName={user.last_name}
              version={Verse.version_id.label}
              userLikesArray={userLikesArray}
          onUpdate={getVerses}
        />
      ))}
    </article>
  );
}
```